# SQL NOT query returns wrong results

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 SQL tables. **users** contains users and **registrants** contains all the registrations done for an event. Given that I have the id of the event - I am successfully printing out those users that are registered for a specific event. However I want to print all the users that are NOT registered for the event and here I fail at producing the correct result. My query is as follows:

```
SELECT users.fName, users.lName, users.uid
FROM users, registrants
WHERE registrants.tourId = '$id' AND NOT registrants.pId = users.uid
```

The result of this is an array of 33 users printed out, although  I have only 12, 3 of which are already registered for the event. Is the SELECT command wrong or I will need to dig into the php code, although I am pretty sure all the work there is correct.

Comment: you should be using the proper join syntax, and then it's a simple right outer join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By specifying no `JOIN` syntax, but instead specifying a kind of inequality join in the `WHERE` clause, you are effectively asking SQL to find all combinations of users and registrants, with the additional filter criteria in the `WHERE` clause, hence the large number of rows.

I believe the query you are looking for is more like this:

```
SELECT users.fName, users.lName, users.uid
FROM users
WHERE users.uid NOT IN (
   SELECT registrants.pId 
   FROM registrants
   WHERE registrants.tourId = '$id');
```

"Find all users, except those registered for tourId = '$id'"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "registrants.pId" is the foreign key to the table "users", this request will give you every combination of registrants and users where the registrant and user are not related.

The way I see you could achieve the intended result is to select users using a subquery to exclude those who are regitered to the event. Which would look something like :

```
$query = "SELECT users.fName, users.lName, users.uid FROM users WHERE users.uid not in (SELECT users.uid FROM users, registrants WHERE registrants.tourId = '$id' AND registrants.pId = users.uid)"
```

there might be a simpler way to do this, though I do not see it right now.

Comment: Correct, unfortunately it was already answered by a colleague here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ".... AND registrants.pld <> users.uid"; ?

or

".... AND registrants.pld != users.uid";

Comment: Same results. No success :|

Comment: could you post a couple entries to both tables so I can understand the setup a bit better?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an anti-join, that is, an outer join where you want to return from the dependent side of the join values where the independent side of the join is null.

In your case that looks like this:

```
SELECT users.fName, users.lName, users.uid
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN registrants
ON users.uid = registrants.pId
AND registrants.tourId = '$id'
WHERE registrants.pId IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the query returned 0 rows. I find it a bit complicated to understand this and I will make sure to dig more into the concepts of anti-join. I made sure to replace $id with the appropriate value so I'm guessing something else is wrong. The answer before yours is working correctly.

Comment: @KalinVarbanov Yes, it was my mistake, the `AND registrants.tourId = '$id'` portion should have been in the JOIN clause rather than the WHERE clause of the query.